# Wanted: example of a non-stationary sequence with reverse empirical measure

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, martingales

Assume we have a sequence $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\dots)$ of random variables such that $$\eta=\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{\xi_i}}{n}\right)_{n\geq 1}$$ is a reverse-martingale with respect to its own tail $\mathcal{T}_n=\sigma(\eta_n,\eta_{n+1},\dots)$. Does it necessarily hold that $\xi$ is stationary? A counterexample would also be of great help.

Comment: What is $\delta_{\xi_i}$?

Comment: It is the Dirac measure: $\delta_x(A)=1_{A}(x)$.

Comment: In this case, what is $A$?

Comment: Any measurable set on the space of definition of $x$. For simplicity assume that this space is the real numbers with the borel field.